# Как оптимизировать связи между таблицами?

Tags: база-данных, mysql-workbench, модель-данных, реляционная-модель

помощи, совета в составлении связей между таблицами сайта с постами.
Ниже я расставил связи но я не могу отделаться от ощущения что можно было сделать по другому или более правильней что-ли.

Помогите мне пожалуйста развеять мои сомнения и дайте свое экспертное мнение.

Спасибо.
[image: MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выглядит нормально, все связи между таблицами вполне логичны, мне непонятно только, почему у постов поле `keywords` не нормализовано (не вынесено в справочник), так как это сделано с `categories`, или это не то, что я думаю?
Ещё непонятно, что там в `description`, если это обычное текстовое поле, то вопросов нет.
У `users` можно вынести в справочники `name` и `surname` для экономии места, но можно этого и не делать, если пользователей не миллионы, то экономия на этом будет не сильно большая, да и редактирование этих полей при наличии справочников будет более муторно происходить.

Comment: в keywords/description у меня будут хранится информация для мета тегов (СЕО) и я подумал что для них не стоит делать отдельные таблицы (может я ошибаюсь), а на счет полей name и surname для сайта блога не думаю что пользователей будет прям миллионы но возможность регистрации других пользователей предусмотрена

Comment: @JonYanjoly Ну если эти теги будут состоять из наборов слов и фраз, то эти слова и фразы наверное надо вынести в справочники. Но в общем это уже мелочи, в целом у вас вполне норм архитектура на вид

Comment: так же keywords и description формирующийся при создание поста (как СЕО атрибуты) как их можно вывести в отдельный справочник?